# Where to set source of application.yml in Java Spring when using classpath; currently uses sub module

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a project with some main source code (Reading Configurations and StartUp-Listener to start several services) and multiple submodules. There are resource-folders in the main project as well as in the sub modules. Currently, I have to store the application.yml in one of the submodules; the application.yml in my main source resources is ignored.

*Project-Structure:*

```
-Main
   -SubModule1
   -Submodule2
    -main
      -resources
       -config
        -application.yml_  
   -Submodule3
   -MainSourceCode (including the submodules)
    -main
      -resources
       -config
        -application.yml
```

Remarks:

- The name of the whole project used to be the name of Submodule2 (so, there might be some config leftover)
- If I rename the application.yml_ in Submodule2 to application.yml, everything works

That's, how I read the configuration:

```
@Configuration
@Order(100)
@PropertySources({
  @PropertySource(value = "file:../../../../../resources/config/application.yml", ignoreResourceNotFound = true),
  @PropertySource("classpath:/config/application.yml")
})
public class AuthorizationControllerConfiguration {
...
```

I receive the output:

```
2019-08-28 08:49:58.054  INFO 19812 --- [           main] o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassParser         : Properties location [file:../../../../../resources/config/application.yml] not resolvable: ..\..\..\..\..\resources\config\application.yml (System cannot find file)
2019-08-28 08:49:58.054  WARN 19812 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [de.......AuthorizationControllerConfiguration]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [config/application.yml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Config1 is ignored as expected, Config2 is - whyever - read from the SubModule2, not from the main module

So, basically my program (run from IntelliJ btw.) selects from the wrong source.

Where do I have to look at to change the source of "classpath"?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the `@PropertySources` annotation does not work for YML files out of the box see this [blog](https://mdeinum.github.io/2018-07-04-PropertySource-with-yaml-files/)

To resolve the issue, you will need to add a custom PropertySourceFactory.

**Also, from the previously mentioned blog post:**

```
public class YamlPropertySourceFactory implements PropertySourceFactory {

    @Override
    public PropertySource<?> createPropertySource(@Nullable String name, EncodedResource resource) throws IOException {
        Properties propertiesFromYaml = loadYamlIntoProperties(resource);
        String sourceName = name != null ? name : resource.getResource().getFilename();
        return new PropertiesPropertySource(sourceName, propertiesFromYaml);
    }

    private Properties loadYamlIntoProperties(EncodedResource resource) throws FileNotFoundException {
        try {
            YamlPropertiesFactoryBean factory = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
            factory.setResources(resource.getResource());
            factory.afterPropertiesSet();
            return factory.getObject();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // for ignoreResourceNotFound
            Throwable cause = e.getCause();
            if (cause instanceof FileNotFoundException)
                throw (FileNotFoundException) e.getCause();
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

**This should address the issue.**